# Cannot modify user Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server

Trying to save logged in parse user's value, it only works for the first time but when i close the app and reopen it, it doesn't work again.

This is the save code I'm using which seems alright

```
PFUser.current()["about"] = textfield.text
PFUser.current().saveInBackground()
```

and this is the error i get when trying to save the objects to current user.

```
PFKeychainStore failed to set object for key 'currentUser', with error: -34018 
or
cannot modify user objectIDxx
```

This started happening after i installed parse server instead of parse.com

Answer (score 1):

Were you using "revocable sessions" before?  If not, parse-server requires you to use them.  You can check out the migration tutorial [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial).

You'll need to add this after you initialize parse:

```
[PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground]
```

And then you will need to re-login a user if you get an 'invalid session' error from parse.

```
// Swift
class ParseErrorHandlingController {
  class func handleParseError(error: NSError) {
    if error.domain != PFParseErrorDomain {
      return
    }

    switch (error.code) {
    case kPFErrorInvalidSessionToken:
      handleInvalidSessionTokenError()

    ... // Other Parse API Errors that you want to explicitly handle.
  }

  private class func handleInvalidSessionTokenError() {
    //--------------------------------------
    // Option 1: Show a message asking the user to log out and log back in.
    //--------------------------------------
    // If the user needs to finish what they were doing, they have the opportunity to do so.
    //
    // let alertView = UIAlertView(
    //   title: "Invalid Session",
    //   message: "Session is no longer valid, please log out and log in again.",
    //   delegate: nil,
    //   cancelButtonTitle: "Not Now",
    //   otherButtonTitles: "OK"
    // )
    // alertView.show()

    //--------------------------------------
    // Option #2: Show login screen so user can re-authenticate.
    //--------------------------------------
    // You may want this if the logout button is inaccessible in the UI.
    //
    // let presentingViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    // let logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
    // presentingViewController?.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

// In all API requests, call the global error handler, e.g.
let query = PFQuery(className: "Object")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // Query Succeeded - continue your app logic here.
  } else {
    // Query Failed - handle an error.
    ParseErrorHandlingController.handleParseError(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this, still happening, deleted my app, made new account. not sure what's exactly wrong.